# Consulta MySQL Asincrona C# Winforms Controlador

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta de forma asincrona con la finalidad de no dejar mi formulario freezeado una vez que se ejecuta el controlador.

Es por esto que intente realizar un metodo asincrono que me resuelva este inconveniente.

Así es como cargo el datagridview mediante el controlador
Main Form

```
private void loadDGV()
{
    dgvHistory.DataSource = _ctrlVehicles.query(null);
}
```

Vehicles Controller

```
public async Task<List<object>> query(string data)
        {
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            List<Object> list = new List<object>();
            string sql;

            if (data == null)
            {
                sql = "SELECT allmyparameters ORDER BY id DESC";
            }

            try
            {
                MySqlConnection dbcon = base.conexion();
                await dbcon.OpenAsync();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, dbcon);

                reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                await Task.Run(()=> while (reader.Read())) /// ERROR
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Vehicles _vehicles = new Vehicles();
                        _vehicles.Id = int.Parse(reader.GetString(0));
                        _vehicles.Name = reader.GetString(1).ToString();
                        _vehicles.Driver = reader.GetString(2).ToString();
                        _vehicles.Ignition = bool.Parse(reader.GetString(3));
                        _vehicles.Temperature = int.Parse(reader.GetString(4));
                        _vehicles.Kms_today = int.Parse(reader.GetString(5));
                        _vehicles.Kms_total = int.Parse(reader.GetString(6));
                        _vehicles.Alerts = int.Parse(reader.GetString(7));
                        _vehicles.Location = reader.GetString(8).ToString();
                        _vehicles.Speed = int.Parse(reader.GetString(9));
                        _vehicles.Trips = int.Parse(reader.GetString(10));
                        _vehicles.Lastupdate = reader.GetString(11).ToString().Replace("/", "-");
                        _vehicles.Status = reader.GetString(12).ToString();
                        list.Add(_vehicles);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Se que no es lo apropiado, pero quisiera obtener alternativas para solventar este problema.

Comment: la alternativa es usar el metodo executereaderasync.. no? y usar el await ahi...

Comment: y de paso, aca => dgvHistory.DataSource = _ctrlVehicles.query(null); no deberias hacer un await tambien? si no, lo asincronico se pierde...

Comment: Y te funciona? Tambien puedes usar la clase Thread

Answer (score 0):

Espero mi aporte te ayude.

Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
    public async Task<DataTable> GetVehicles()
    {
        // tarea a realizar
        var task = Task<DataTable>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // datos a retornar
            var vehicles = new DataTable();
            // conexión con MySQL
            using (MySqlConnection dbcon = Servidor.ObtenerConexion())
            {
                // consulta a ejecutar en MySQL
                MySqlCommand query = new MySqlCommand()
                {
                    CommandText = "SELECT allmyparameters ORDER BY id DESC",
                    Connection = dbcon,
                    CommandType = CommandType.Text
                };
                dbcon.OpenAsync();
                // aquí llenamos el DataTable con los datos obtenidos de la consulta
                using (var dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query))
                {
                    dataAdapter.FillAsync(vehicles);
                }
                dbcon.CloseAsync();
                dbcon.Dispose();
            }
            // retornamos los datos
            return vehicles;
        });
        // esperando respuesta
        return await task;
    }
```

Y para mostrarlo en el DataGridView sería

```
    private async void LoadDgv()
    {
        dgvHistory.DataSource = await GetVehicles();
    }
```